# how to calculate multipath signal, delay, angle between 2 signal?

Tags: python, signal-processing, software-defined-radio

I am trying to understand how to calculate the phase angle, delay, and multipath signal. I hope everyone can help me for ideas.

My scenario: I have a radio hardware (SDR) with rx1 and rx2, and the TV station (center frequency = 533MHZ, bandwidth = 6MHz), with 4.8 km distance away from me (from google map to measure a distance). From FCC data base that I have information for the TX (latitude, longitude, antenna height, and model...).

First, I calculate the phase between 2 antennas:

%%%%%%

```
x = .... ; % complex data from rx1

y = .... ; % complex data from rx2

x = x - mean(x);  X = fft(x);
y = y - mean(y);  Y = fft(y);

[mag_x idx_x] = max(abs(X));
[mag_y idx_y] = max(abs(Y));

px = angle(X(idx_x));
py = angle(Y(idx_y));
phase_lag = py - px;
```

%%%%%

is it correct? then trying to calculate the multipath signal:

```
speed_of_light = 3e8 ; % m/s
distance = 3 * 1.6;
freq = 533e6;
lamda = speed_of_light / freq;
k = 2 * pi / lamda;
x = distance / 2;
y = 0;
w = 2 * pi * freq;
phase = 0;
delta = 1e-6; % delay
i = sqrt(-1);
t = 0:0.01:1;
degree = 0;
mutilpath = zeros(1,length(t));

index = 10;

for j = 1: index

   mutilpath  = mutilpath + exp(i * (k * (x * cos(phase+degree) + y * sin(phase+degree)) - w * (t - delta)));
    degree    = degree + pi/6;

end

figure(1), plot(t,abs(mutilpath));
figure(2), plot(t,angle(mutilpath));

%figure(3), plot(t,abs(mutilpath));
%figure(4), plot(t,angle(mutilpath));
```

%%%%%%%%%

when i set index = 1; i have a plot abs(mutilpath) is a straight line (figure1)

when i set index = ! 1; i have a plot abs(mutilpath) is a different line (figure3)

I have a bad feeling that i am not doing right.

If everyone have ideas, please recommend.

Thank you very much.